# Connect to Websphere Liberty jmsServer from remote application server

Tags: java, jms, websphere-liberty

Is it possible to connect to a queue deployed in Websphere Liberty from a remote application server?

I use the free version of the product (Liberty 8.5.5.7).
I configured connection factory in server.xml:

```xml
<messagingEngine>
    <queue id="Queue1" receivedAllowed="false" maxMessageDepth="1000"/>
</messagingEngine>

<jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="qcf/ConnectionFactory" connectionManagerRef="ConMgr2">
    <properties.wasJms nonPersistentMapping="ExpressNonPersistent" persistentMapping="ReliablePersistent"/>
</jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
<connectionManager id="ConMgr2" maxPoolSize="10"/>
```

The jms server is listening on localhost:7276.

I wrote a simple client application and include the necessary client jars in the classpath (com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar, com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar and com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_8.5.0.jar):

```java
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://localhost:7276");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
Object qcf = ctx.lookup("qcf/ConnectionFactory");
```

Running the program produces this exception:

```
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: A communication failure occurred while attempting to obtain an initial context with the provider URL: "iiop://localhost:7276".  Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.  A bootstrap address with no port specification defaults to port 2809.  Possible causes other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server include the network environment and workstation network configuration. [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect:host=192.168.9.208,port=7276  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3586  completed: No]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mapInitialReferenceFailure(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:2373)
```

The original IBM documentation does not discuss clearly, if this feature is disabled or not in Liberty.

**Solution:**
It is not possible to use remote lookup with JNDI in Liberty.
Using this forum topic: [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014949432), it is possible to construct the ConnectionFactory programatically.

```java
JmsFactoryFactory jff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance();
JmsQueueConnectionFactory qcf = jff.createQueueConnectionFactory();
qcf.setBusName("myBus");
qcf.setProviderEndpoints("localhost:7276:BootstrapBasicMessaging");
qcf.setTargetTransportChain("InboundBasicMessaging");
```

You need only this jars in the classpath: com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar, com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_8.5.0.jar. (Found in WebSphere\AppServer\runtimes, where WebSphere is the full WAS installation directory)

Comment: No, the Liberty profile (unlike the full profile) does not make the default JNDI namespace remotely accessible, so this is not possible.  I suspect it is possible to access Liberty JMS server without using JNDI, but I do not have enough expertise with JMS to give any suggestions.

Comment: You can access the JMS externally, but you'd need to either use the programatic APIs to create the connection factory and destinations, or bind them into an external JNDI name server.

Comment: Alasdir, please add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution.