# Weblogic and Websphere JMS Queue Communication

Tags: queue, jms, websphere, weblogic

Currently in Weblogic we are running two applications and communicating through JMS Queue. Now one of the application we are moving to Liberty Server. What are the configuration we need to do for JMS Queue connection between Weblogic and Websphere.

Comment: Are you using internal WebLogic JMS provider or some external one?

Comment: We are using Weblogic internal JMS provider.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which JMS Provider are you using, you have several options:

- if provider has compatible JMS Resource Adapter (e.g. WebSphere MQ) - you can use that RA together with Liberty jca feature
- if provider has a sort of *thin client*, you can embed that client libraries together with your application, and manually setup connection
- if your current provider doesn't support any of above, you can use external JMS server that has compatible JMS RA (for example WebSphere MQ) and integrate it with both WebLogic and Liberty.

Update based on comments

There is no simple way to access Liberty JNDI externally - see this post [Connect to Websphere Liberty jmsServer from remote application server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822240/connect-to-websphere-liberty-jmsserver-from-remote-application-server)

You could try to access embedded JMS via API. It is discussed here: https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062ktc3CAA/helloworld-jms-client-connecting-to-embedded-liberty-jms-server?language=en_US

But to be honest, if I were you I would either:

- use external JMS Provider that is compatible with both runtimes e.g. WebSphere MQ
- or rewrite interface between WebLogic and Liberty to REST, so that WebLogic invokes via REST simple application that reads the request and puts it to the queue in embedded Liberty JMS engine to avoid calling JMS engine externally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, need another clarification, in weblogic we are using the t3 protocol (example : t3://localhost:9081) to communicate with application running in another weblogic server. Now we moved application to liberty server, what protocol we need to use and what initial context we need for communication (as of now we are using "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory").

Comment: You dont use specific InitialContextFactory, just use protocol you need, if you have http endpoint then http.

Comment: ok sure, i need to post the request from WebLogic server to liberty server queue, i tried with default initial context it is not working, do we need to define the initial context like following                                         
 env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
 env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://localhost:9081");
Context context = new InitialContext(env);                                                                          If i have above code i am getting the following error

Comment: Dec 03, 2020 3:11:56 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.legacy.connection.SocketFactoryConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 127.0.0.1; port: 9081"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No

Comment: My exact logic is, xml request generated in application running in WebLogic server i need to post that request to queue in liberty server, before both run in the WebLogic now moved one of them to liberty, so i need to modify this code to post the request to liberty server queue from WebLogic server application.